# Same as billing/shipping checkbox in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hello im just trying to make a simple same as billing checkbox in knockout. Here is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/neosketo/kmwpop19/1/

my javascript would work in jquery but i dont want to use  jquery:

```
var MainViewModel = function () {
var self = this;
self.States = ko.observableArray([{Value:"CA",Name:"California"},
                                                                    {Value:"FL",Name:"Florida"},
                                  {Value:"NY",Name:"New York"},
                                  {Value:"VG",Name:"Virginia"},
                                  {Value:"TX",Name:"Texas"}
                                ]);


    self.SelectedState = ko.observable();
    self.SelectedShippingState = ko.observable();

self.myValue = ko.observable(false);
self.myAction = function() {
            if (self.myValue) {
        this.SelectedShippingState().Value = this.SelectedState().Value;
    } else {
        self.SelectedShippingState().Value = null;
    }       
    return true;
};



  }
  ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use both the `checked` and the `click` bindings.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myValue, click: myAction" /> Same as Billing<br/>
```

Once you've bound the checkbox to a variable, subscribe to it to deal with changes:

```
self.myValue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  if (newValue) {
    self.SelectedShippingState(self.SelectedState());
  } else {
    self.SelectedShippingState(null);
  }
});
```

You had a number of other problems with your code, in terms of what to use for bindings and where `Value` comes into play. Here it is corrected:

```js
var MainViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.States = ko.observableArray([{
    Value: "CA",
    Name: "California"
  }, {
    Value: "FL",
    Name: "Florida"
  }, {
    Value: "NY",
    Name: "New York"
  }, {
    Value: "VG",
    Name: "Virginia"
  }, {
    Value: "TX",
    Name: "Texas"
  }]);


  self.SelectedState = ko.observable();
  self.SelectedShippingState = ko.observable();

  self.myValue = ko.observable(false);
  self.myValue.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      self.SelectedShippingState(self.SelectedState());
    } else {
      self.SelectedShippingState(null);
    }
    return true;
  });
}
ko.applyBindings(new MainViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Billing State:
<select data-bind="options: States, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Value', value: SelectedState, optionsCaption: 'Choose a Billing State'"></select>
<hr/>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myValue" />Same as Billing
<br/>Shipping State:
<select data-bind="options: States, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Value', value: SelectedShippingState, optionsCaption: 'Choose a Shipping State'"></select>
<br>
```

Note that if you check the box and then change the first pulldown, they don't stay in sync. That would require the second to be a computed.